# Review guidelines for new and late posts

Tags: support, review

I have read following posts regarding review tasks

[Is it okay to just say “no action needed” if a post in the review queue has already been edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161429/is-it-okay-to-just-say-no-action-needed-if-a-post-in-the-review-queue-has-alre)

[What are the limits on using the “no action needed” button in the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158764/what-are-the-limits-on-using-the-no-action-needed-button-in-the-review-queue)

[What to do when reviewing a good Q/A?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5831/what-to-do-when-reviewing-a-good-q-a)

[Processing the Review / Late Answers queue](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4005/processing-the-review-late-answers-queue)

and this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160314/are-posts-removed-from-the-review-queue-if-they-get-a-no-action-needed-review)

and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158983/both-no-action-needed-and-im-done-enabled-when-reviewing-a-post-for-the-sec)

and [this](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/review-etiquette-re-obviously-incorrect-or-irrelevant-answers)

When I review a post I look for the following basic criteria:

1. It should not be a spam
2. Question should be relevant to the forum
3. Answer should be an answer (not another question)
4. If any edits are required to improve the structure of the post

I do flag if the post needs attention (not an answer, spam, off topic, etc). I do edit the post if it needs an edit. If the post doesn't need attention, I click "no action needed".

Am I doing something wrong by clicking "no action needed" if the post passes above four tests?

Do I need to do more checks? If yes, are they documented somewhere or am I not looking hard enough?

Is is mandatory for me to vote the post up or down if I don't feel it is needed?

Answer (score 5):

That about seems right. If you have a post which doesn't need any changes to be done, then "no action needed" is the right course of action. Vote up/down is **not** mandatory - the point of review queues is to ensure that the post has been vetted properly, not to be artificially inflated/deflated for whatever reasons

Comment: That being said, IMO *no action needed* should always be the last choice together with skipping the review item. I'm very confident that first questions and answers can always be edited into better shape to guide new users.